# Why does the ComponentEvent listener in Vaadin not work as expected

Tags: vaadin

I have my main view (AppLayout) with has a menu component. Then I have another view (VerticalLayout) which has three tabs that corresponds with the details (submenu) of a menu entry. Is there a way to tell the menu component the current selected tab, that the style or text of a search field could be adapted according to the selected tab?

The problem is that I do not have access to the instance of the view from the menu component so I cannot attach a listener to the view.

**Update**

I added a custom event now which holds the Label of the tab which also should be shown as placeholder text in the MainView's menu component.

```
public class TabChangeEvent extends ComponentEvent<MyTabView> {

    private final String selectedTab;

    public TabChangeEvent(MyTabView source, String selectedTab) {
        super(source, false);
        this.selectedTab = selectedTab;
    }

    public String getSelectedTab() {
        return selectedTab;
    }
}
```

And a listener within the MainView which contains the search field and menu component with

```
addListener(TabChangeEvent.class, this::changeSearchFieldPlaceholder);

private void changeSearchFielPlaceholder(TabChangeEvent event) {
    menuComponent.updateSearchFieldPlaceholderText(event.getSelectedTab());
}
```

Within the TabView there is a selectionChangeListener for the tabs which then also fires the event.

```
    TabChangeEvent event = new TabChangeEvent(this, tabLabel);
    fireEvent(event);
```

The event is fired as expected but the method changeSearchFieldPlaceholder within the MainView is not called.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fireEvent()` only notifies itself (the component it was fired from) and the children of the component about the event. If you need to inform siblings or even parent components about an event, you have fire the event e.g. on UI-level (which represents the most outer component of the whole page).

You can find an example in the official Cookbook by Vaadin: https://cookbook.vaadin.com/ui-eventbus